# Can I widen the hole with a drill to straighten the handle?

Tags: kitchens, woodworking, drill, wood-filler

I messed up the measurements of one of the IKEA kitchen handles. 32mm Vs 29mm to the edge, so 3mm off.

Do you think I can drill to widen one hole left 1.5mm and the other hole right by 1.5mm and then tighten it straight without exposing the mess from the front or back? Is a 3mm move too much?
I'm willing to accept a half way house and maybe trim the discrepancy from 3mm to 1.5mm etc
If not what do you suggest?
Fill and re-drill?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Making the hole wider will simply allow the handle to slide back & forth, no matter how tight you get the screw today. It will loosen and slide as you grab the handle to open the door. Once it's starting to slide around, it will scratch up the surface of your cabinet and you'll have a scratched door with a crooked handle, instead of a nice looking door with a crooked handle. _Widening_ the hole is _not_ recommended!

Answer (score 2):

I would plug both holes without enlarging them, glue a piece of dowel that fits and let dry.

Then check on the face that the handle will cover the dowel when the handle is mounted correctly, otherwise you will need to make it the same color.

Then drill new holes in the correct positions. The back side may be easily covered by using a washer or a screw with a wider head - usually the screws for those handles have a washer built into the head anyway.

The adage: **measure twice, cut once** also applies to drilling.

Answer (score 1):

How wide is this?

[image]

It looks like you have enough room to adjust it 1.5-3mm in either direction.

I suggest:

1. Removing the handle
2. Clean the hole by drilling through it with a bit as wide as the screw threads. If the screw threads did not damage the interior of the original hole then skip this step unless you need to enlarge it for step #3.
3. Get a bunch of toothpicks, match sticks, or a dowel
4. Generously apply wood glue to them
5. Hammer them into the hole
6. Clean up excess wood glue
7. Wait for the glue to cure
8. Use a sharp knife or chisel and carefully remove the excess toothpick/match/dowel
9. Re-drill your hole where desired

I do this all the time when I replace the strike plate on a doorframe. Albeit I benefit from the strike plate covering up my mess quite well :-)

---

If all else fails then order a replacement door from IKEA.

Comment: 16mm. Would you not consider just widening the whole or is that too much of a bodge?

Comment: @J12966 The cabinet handle would forever be at risk of shifting when you use it and will mess up the finish of the cabinet door.

Comment: @J12966 Here's the damage a loose door knob does to a door's finish: https://www.locksmithsmelbourne.biz/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/loose-door-knob-web-300x227.jpg Sure, you could tighten it really hard but then you might crack your cabinet. Over time it **will** loosen.